# Access statistics from a Facebook Business account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, statistics, account

I am the website developer for a company and I want to show statistics from social networks on our site. Facebook has put me through a loop. The fb account was created as a business and I know now that business accounts cannot create or edit apps with the FB API.

Is there any way access analytics/statistics without an App ID and secret? or do I have to make a personal account to use the FB API?

A good example of this is [Blackberry's Community](http://ca.blackberry.com/communities/?lid=ca%3abb%3aCommunities&lpos=ca%3abb%3aCommunities) page. I can't tell if they have a personal or business account but it is exactly what I would like to achieve.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/ is a good starting point - should cover what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're after is the number of fans, then this is a doddle.

Take a look at the JSON data for Blackberry's Facebook page:

https://graph.facebook.com/blackberry

There's a `likes` chunk in the JSON data (notice you don't need to be authenticated or require any access token or app id).

To get this for your Page, replace `blackberry` in that URI with your Page's short name or Page ID and you'll get a similar JSON chunk back. Here's Nike's: http://graph.facebook.com/nike

You can fetch this with JSONP on the frontend, or grab the response on the server side and parse it there (probably a good idea to cache it if you do).

Anything more than that will need an App ID, an access token and some FQL.

Comment: This works perfectly for likes. I had to use my Facebook id instead of the page name. ex. http://graph.facebook.com/240723642623125.

Comment: That answered my question but I realized I want to get recent posts as well to be displayed. I guess if I want to go that far I would have to make a personal account to access the api.

Comment: Yes, you need to get an access token and the `manage_pages` permission to access posts on a page. You could always use some of the social plugins to get likes and page activity, like the Like Box: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ - doesn't look too pretty though!

If it works for you, please accept the answer!